# Setting per-build DefaultValue in Settings.bundle/Root.plist

Tags: xcode, plist

I have two custom build configs `development` and `release` with some values defined. Here is what my `Development.xcconfig` looks like:

```
//
// Development .xcconfig
//

// Include Pods config.
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp.debug.xcconfig"

// Server URL
HOST_NAME = 127.0.0.1:6060
// Use TLS (https, wss)
USE_TLS = NO

// App Settings
APP_NAME = MyApp (test)
APP_BUNDLE_ID = co.my-domain.myapp-test
```

I reference these values in `Info.plist` as `$(HOST_NAME)` and it works fine. But I also want to expose these custom parameters in application preferences as `DefaultValue`. I.e. I want the app to use `localhost:6060` as default host name preference when the target is `development` and the address of production host when the target is `release`.

The preferences are defined in `Settings.bundle/Root.plist`. Unfortunately xcode does not expand references like `$(HOST_NAME)` in `Settings.bundle/Root.plist`. I suppose I have to write a build script to update the values. I know how to use `PlistBuddy` to update entries in `Root.plist`. What I can't figure out is how to *read* values from `Info.plist` and at what point in the build process I should update `Root.plist`.

I can't read `Info.plist` early in the build because the values are not yet expanded. The host name still reads as literal string `"$(HOST_NAME)"`.

I suppose I can read the `Info.plist` as the last step in the build process and then update `"$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH/Settings.bundle/Root.plist"`, but which `Info.plist` to read, the one at
`"$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"` or the one at 
`"$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME/Contents/Info.plist"`??? Does it matter? Are they always the same? Are they both always present?

Thanks!